# Why does my attempt to use Perl's stat function on Windows fail?

Tags: perl

I could not figure out how to reopen the previous question. here is reference.
 [Using Perl stat function on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201565/using-perl-stat-function-on-windows/30201966#30201966)

I used your second suggestion and it worked for files with no spaces in the path-file-name. however many of the ones I am working with have spaces included.
My searching indicates that the string should be within double quotes to resolve this problem. I have made a few attempts with various outcomes.

This code reads a file that contains a list of path-file-name entries. I read each one in and try to run stat on the full entry. There are duplicate entries with different size and date attributes. This is due to entries being on separate drives. I want to output the path-file-name, size, date attributes to another file. I would then use a sort function to put out a list sorted by the full path with date and size to allow deletion of unneeded entries after evaluating the list.

This is the code for reading the path-file-name entries and trying to perform the stat function.

```
my $record = 0;
my $time   = 0;
my $size   = 0; 
my $quote   = '"';              # single quote, double quote, single quote

print "quote = $quote \n";
                                # read lines from listing file
open (ALL_, "<", $filename);    # open my file list for reading
while (defined($_ = <ALL_>))    # while(my $line = <$
{   chomp;                      # remove newline "/n" 
    print " Normal value = $_\n"; # status output
    $record = $_;
    $record =~ s/\\/\//g;       # change \ to /
    $record = "\"$record\"";    # add single double quote to start and end of record
#   $record = $quote . $record . $quote;
    print " now = $record \n";

#   use lib '/home/foobar/code';  ?? add dbl quotes
#   use My::Module;

    # Using File::stat, which replaces stat with a function with a friendlier interface:
    use File::stat qw( stat );
    use POSIX      qw( strftime );
#   my $qfn = $quote . $_ . $quote;  # also adds double quote
    my $qfn = $record; 
    my $stat = stat($qfn)   or die("Can't stat \"$qfn\": $!\n");

    printf("File %s: size=%s modified=%s\n",
        $qfn,
        $stat->size,
        strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($stat->mtime)), 
    );
}
```

---

This gets

```
Normal value = N:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1
now          = "N:/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1"
Can't stat ""N:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1"": No such file or directory
```

Quits because of   or die(can't stat \"qfn\": $!\n");

---

if I comment out line

```
$record = "\"$record\"";
```

to leave off the double quotes I get:

```
normal value = N:\dir1\dir2\dir3file1
now = N:/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1
file N:/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1: size=280580 modified=20022-12-13 09:41:28
normal value = C:\dir01\dir 02\dir03\file 2
now = C:/dir01/dir 02/dir03/file 2
Can't stat "C:/dir1/dir 02/dir03/file2": No such file or directory
```

Quits because of   or die(can't stat \"qfn\": $!\n");

---

Is there something different about stat that it handles double quotes differently such that it still sees the spaces?

If I can get this all executing correctly: 
Is there a way to allow or die() to provide a message that indicates a failure and goes on processing for that one file that somehow got deleted during processing?

Comment: `stat` works for me with spaces on Windows (8.1), no quotes needed.  Also, this question is kind of a mess--the output you claim to get in your first example was clearly not produced by the version of the code shown above.  Can you please cut it down to a simpler example (remove commented lines, etc) and show the output from that exact code?

Comment: Why are you writing **`while (defined($_ = <ALL_>)) `**? Instead, use `while (my $line = <$all>)` ... i.e. instead of the topical variable `$_`, use your own lexically scoped `$line`, and instead of a bareword filehandle, use a lexical filehandle.

Comment: Don't invent your own filename handling routines. Use [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec), or, [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class), or [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny). `stat` on Windows will work just fine with any mixture of / and \ as separators in a file name, but if you did want to canonicalize strings you show users or pass to other programs, you would use `canonpath`.

Answer (score 0):

None of what you are saying seems to be consistent with anything I know about paths etc on Windows. Here is a sample program that stats a bunch of files with spaces in their names:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catdir catpath rootdir);

use File::Find;

my %number_of = (
    files_with_spaces_for_which_stat_was_successful => 0,
    files_with_spaces_seen => 0,
);

my $top = catpath('C:', catdir(rootdir(), 'Program Files', 'Internet Explorer'));
print "calling stat for every file under '$top'\n";

find({
    no_chdir => 1,
    wanted => sub {
        next unless /\s/;
        $number_of{files_with_spaces_seen} += 1;
        print "$_: ";
        if (stat) {
            $number_of{files_with_spaces_for_which_stat_was_successful} += 1;
            print "+\n";
        }
        else {
            print "-\n";
        }
    },
}, $top);

use YAML::XS;
print Dump \%number_of;
```

Output:

```
C:\> perl t.pl
...
---
files_with_spaces_for_which_stat_was_successful: 171
files_with_spaces_seen: 171
```